# Another Repeated column in mapping for entity error

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, mappingexception

Despite all of the others post, I can't find a solution for this error with GlassFish, on MacOSX, NetBeans 7.2.

```
Here the error :
SEVERE: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer
prepare method
SEVERE: Exception while preparing the app
SEVERE: [PersistenceUnit: supmarket] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory

...

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity:
com.supmarket.entity.Sale column: customerId
(should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

Here the code :

**Sale.java**

```
@Entity
public class Sale {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Long idFromAgency;

    private float amountSold;

    private String agency;

    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date createdate;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Long productId;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Long customerId;

    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="productId",referencedColumnName="id_product")
    private Product product;

    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="customerId",referencedColumnName="id_customer")
    private Customer customer;


    public void Sale(){}    
    public void Sale(Long idFromAgency, float amountSold, String agency
            , Date createDate, Long productId, Long customerId){        
        ...
    }

    // then getters/setters
}
```

**Customer.java**

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id_customer")
    private Long id_customer;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Long idFromAgency;

    private String  gender,
                    maritalState,
                    firstname,
                    lastname,
                    incomeLevel;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer",targetEntity=Sale.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection sales;


    public void Customer(){}

    public void Customer(Long idFromAgency, String gender, String maritalState,
            String firstname, String lastname, String incomeLevel) {
        ...
    }

}
```

**Product.java**

```
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id_product")
    private Long id_product;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Long idFromAgency;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="product",targetEntity=Sale.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection sales;

    //constructors + getters +setters
}
```

Answer (score 195, accepted):

The message is clear: you have a repeated column in the mapping. That means you mapped the same database column twice. And indeed, you have:

```
@Column(nullable=false)
private Long customerId;
```

and also:

```
@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name="customerId",referencedColumnName="id_customer")
private Customer customer;
```

(and the same goes for `productId`/`product`).

You shouldn't reference other entities by their ID, but by a direct reference to the entity. Remove the `customerId` field, it's useless. And do the same for `productId`. If you want the customer ID of a sale, you just need to do this:

```
sale.getCustomer().getId()
```

Comment: I get the same error, but my situation is a bit different. My entity can be the father of one or more entities of the same type. The children have a reference on the id of their father as well as a unique id of their own. How can I resolve such a circular dependency?

Comment: @JBNizet How then can I *save* a Sale with some particular `customerId`? (e.g. from JSON).

Comment: `Customer customer = entityManager.getReference(customerId, Customer.class); sale.setCustomer(customer);`

Comment: Wouldn't that do an extra fetch from the DB to get the Customer object just to get it's id, which you already have since you're using it to look up the Customer??

Comment: once you remove customerId, can you still do findByCustomeId(Long customeId) ?

Comment: How do you handle the case where you have a `@EmbeddedId` composite key between `customerId` and another field of the `Customer` class? In this case I need both repeated column in the mapping, am i right?

Comment: @louisamoros Yes, you repeat it, but you add `@MapsId("customerId")`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775055/hibernate-embeddedid-join

Comment: @Ciri, you have to remove from entity a column which is mapped to the same table’s primary key. See here more details https://www.viralpatel.net/hibernate-self-join-annotations-one-to-many-mapping/

Comment: @JBNizet using `sale.getCustomer().getId()` would trigger a join for Customer table? when using LAZY loading?

Comment: Replying to @AnanRaddad, for new users coming here: NO, that expression will not trigger a join. I checked that the join is only triggered if reading another field from customer.

Answer (score 103):

If you are stuck with a legacy database where someone already placed JPA annotations on but did NOT define the relationships and you are now trying to define them for use in your code, then you might NOT be able to delete the customerId `@Column` since other code may directly reference it already.  In that case, define the relationships as follows:

```
@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name="productId",referencedColumnName="id_product", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Product product;

@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name="customerId",referencedColumnName="id_customer", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Customer customer;
```

This allows you to access the relationships.  However, to add/update to the relationships you will have to manipulate the foreign keys directly via their defined `@Column` values.  It's not an ideal situation, but if you are handed this sort of situation, at least you can define the relationships so that you can use JPQL successfully.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the solution I need, besides the `ManyToOne` mapping field, I need a field directly mapped to the join column.

Comment: This is the right solution when you have a field that is foreing key and primary key at the same time.

Answer (score 36):

use this, is work for me:

```
@Column(name = "candidate_id", nullable=false)
private Long candidate_id;
@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name = "candidate_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Candidate candidate;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the solution I need

Comment: Works even with optional=true.

Answer (score 11):

```
@Id
@Column(name = "COLUMN_NAME", nullable = false)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = SomeCustomEntity.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "COLUMN_NAME", referencedColumnName = "COLUMN_NAME", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade(value = org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
public List<SomeCustomEntity> getAbschreibareAustattungen() {
    return abschreibareAustattungen;
}
```

If you have already mapped a column and have accidentaly set the same values for **name** and **referencedColumnName** in **@JoinColumn** hibernate gives the same stupid error

Error:

*Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.testtest.SomeCustomEntity column: COLUMN_NAME (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")*

Comment: A key point here for me was that the error says "should be mapped with insert=false update=false" but the actual parameters/methods should be "insertable=false, updatable=false".

Comment: I suspect that's the reason (or at least one of them) why dbow qualifies the error as "stupid", @NightOwl. I thought exactly the same when I experienced it. To add up, the error is even farther stupid, as it adds double brackets between the "false" (as dbow noted), when in fact the proper syntax is WITHOUT quotes.

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help!**

```
@OneToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Department department;

@JsonIgnore
    public Department getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "department")
private Designation designation;

@JsonIgnore
    public Designation getDesignation() {
        return designation;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR")
private String contribution_id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "contribution_id",insertable=false, updatable=false) 
private ClimateChangeContribution climateChangeContribution;
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Take care to provide only 1 setter and getter for any attribute. The best way to approach is to write down the definition of all the attributes then use eclipse generate setter and getter utility rather than doing it manually. The option comes on right click-> source -> Generate Getter and Setter.

Answer (score 0):

This means you are mapping a column twice in your entity class. 
Explaining with an example...

```java
    @Column(name = "column1")
    private String object1;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "column1", referencedColumnName = "column1")
    private TableClass object2;
```

> The problem in the above code snippet is we are repeating mapping...

**Solution**

Since mapping is an important part, you don't want to remove that. Instead, you will remove

```java
    @Column(name = "column1")
    private String uniqueId;
```

> You can still pass the value of object1 by creating a object of TableClass and assign the String value of Object1 in it.

This works 100%. I have tested this with Postgres and Oracle database.

Answer (score 0):

We have resolved the circular dependency(Parent-child Entities) by mapping the child entity instead of parent entity in Grails 4(GORM).

**Example:**

```
Class Person {
    String name
}

Class Employee extends Person{
    String empId
}

//Before my code 
Class Address {
    static belongsTo = [person: Person]
}

//We changed our Address class to:
Class Address {
    static belongsTo = [person: Employee]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had added OneToMany annotation at two places by mistake where it was not needed, removed it and that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, just  need make different names for id and column
for exemple

```
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name = "id_product")
 private long id;
```