# Many-to-Many JPA Hibernate mapping composite key through join table error

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have the following two classes (and their pk classes) with these annotations. I removed setters/getters/hashcode/equals to compress the example

I am ultimately getting this error

`org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for collection: com.stackOverflow.Features.thingCategory column: YEAR`

My guess is that because "year" is shared in the join table, I have messed up some syntax for associating my entities. Note these are views which have an implicit relationship between their entities, that I am trying to model in my annotations. I have tried some JPA modelling tools which are giving me the same errors after modelling. I have tried setting the join columns to `insertable` and `updatable` to `false` as well.

I can of course just write a SQL query, but I really surprised at how hard this seems to me in Hibernate.

Feature Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "myTableOfFeatures")
public class Feature {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private FeatureKey id;

    @Column(name="displayText")
    private String description;

    //bi-directional many-to-many association
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name="joinTableToThingCategories"
            , joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="name", referencedColumnName="name", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name="year", referencedColumnName="year", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    }
            , inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="year", referencedColumnName="year", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name="title", referencedColumnName="title", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    }
    )
    private List<ThingCategory> thingCategory;

    public Feature() {
    } 
    // ... gets and sets

} 
@Embeddable
public class FeatureKey implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String myName;

    private String year;

    public FeatureKey() {
    }
    // ... gets and sets and equals and hashes
}
```

ThingCategory Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CategoriesOfThings")
public class ThingCategory implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private ThingCategoryKey id;

    private String comment;

    //bi-directional many-to-many association to categories
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="thingCategory")
    private List<Feature> features;

    public ThingCategory() {
    }
    // ... gets and sets
}
@Embeddable
public class ThingCategoryKey implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String year;

    @Column(name="categoryName")
    private String title;

    public ThingCategoryKey() {
    }
    // ... gets and sets and equals and hashes
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure it'll work. You can try add @MapsId("myName") and @MapsId("title"). Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775055/hibernate-embeddedid-join
Let me know it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Where would I add that declaration? on the relationship?

Comment: No, it won't work with @MapsId

Comment: This won't work with a @MapsId?

Comment: No. MapsId is only for OneToOne and OneToMany

Answer (score 0):

This is an example from JPA 2.1 specification.
I hope it helps.

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id int id;
    @Embedded ContactInfo contactInfo;
    ...
}


@Embeddable
public class ContactInfo {
    @ManyToOne Address address; // Unidirectional
    @ManyToMany List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers; // Bidirectional 
}

@Entity
public class PhoneNumber {
    @Id int phNumber; 

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="contactInfo.phoneNumbers")         
    Collection<Employee> employees;
}
```

I highly recommend you this specification. [JPA 2.1](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf)

Comment: I don't think this is encapsulating the complexity of the composite primary keys, with a shared column in the join table.

Answer (score 0):

This might work, but I haven't tried myself; so I wanted to write this as a comment but it is cumbersome to write code as a comment. So you might want to try it if it works (sorry no time to try it out). If it doesn't work leave me a comment and I'll delete it.

```
@JoinTable(
        name="joinTableToThingCategories", 
        joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="feature_name", referencedColumnName="name", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name="feature_year", referencedColumnName="year", insertable = false, updatable = false)
        }, 
        inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="tcat_year", referencedColumnName="year", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name="tcat_title", referencedColumnName="title", insertable = false, updatable = false)
       }
)
private List<ThingCategory> thingCategory;
```

Comment: I could not seem to make this work, but didn't try as many incantations with my JPA annotations as i probably should have to fully test. It did get me going down the right (or wrong) road, and i duplicated the year column in my join table. Ho hum