# Hibernate Mapping same Column twice and insert

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I want to insert a row that contain two filed name organization_id and account_id that is refereed from same table (organization table).

**EntityModel.java**

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "organization_id")
private OrganizationModel organization;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
private OrganizationModel account;
```

**OrganizationModel.java**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "organization_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private int organizationId;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "organization")
private Set<EntityModel> organization;
```

But iam getting following error.

```
Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.party.OrganizationModel column: organization_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

And when i add `insert="false"` `update="false"` for account, error gone.But i need to insert both account and organization at the same time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Another Repeated column in mapping for entity error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076463/another-repeated-column-in-mapping-for-entity-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a primary key for EntityModel.

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EntityModel")
public class EntityModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "entity_model_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int entityModelId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "organization_id")
    private OrganizationModel organization;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
    private OrganizationModel account;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "OrganizationModel")
public class OrganizationModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "organization_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int organizationId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "organization")
    private Set<EntityModel> organization;

}
```

Comment: Where is account_id in your OrganizationModel table?