# Rest API and Hibernate. How to add a new record with foreign key?

Tags: hibernate, rest, join, spring-data

I have this object:

```
public class MerchantDetail {

    private id;
    private boolean optStatus;
    private BigDecimal amountDue;


    @ManyToOne(optional=false) 
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="merchantId") 
    private Merchant merchant;

    //getters and setters
}
```

My table looks like this:

```
`MerchantDetail` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`amountdue` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`optstatus` BIT() DEFAULT NULL,
`merchant_merchantId` varchar(255) NOT NULL //autogenerated by hibernate
)
```

My current codes are using Spring Data JPA using Hibernate.

My Rest API is using Jersey for endpoints and Jackson for marshalling and unmarshalling data.

How am I going to create a new record using JSON?

Comment: do you need to create the merchant too?

Comment: no, the merchant already exists.

Comment: Is your repository a `CrudRepository`? What exactly do you want to do, Insert a record inside Merchant Detail table?

Comment: Yeah it is a CrudRepository. Well, I have a rest endpoint that accepts json and, map it to an object using Jackson and save it using CrudRepository. And you are correct, I am trying to save a new record inside the merchantdetail table

Comment: try this: @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="merchantId", insertable=false, updatable=false) and add a new property `String merchantId` setting the right column name. The json will contain the field merchantId equals to the the merchant key... even if I suggest you to never map directly ORM to exposed objects

Comment: Does this mean that I will have to remove the getter/setter for the reference object as per answer here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076463/another-repeated-column-in-mapping-for-entity-error