# Hibernate: foreign keys instead of list of entites

Tags: java, hibernate, foreign-keys, mapping

There is already a solution - [how to store fk instead the whole entity on many-to-one unidirectional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311776/hibernate-foreign-keys-instead-of-entities):

```
@JoinColumn(name = "message_key")
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Messages.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Messages message;

@Column(name = "message_key", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Long message_fk;
```

Two questions:

1. *How to do the same for unidirectional many-to-many?* Means I have a `List<Message> messages` and want to keep only `List<Long> message_fks`.
2. *Will it ensure consistency if I will never use `message` object?* I want to use only `message_fk` field.