# Obtaining only foreign keys instead of Entities

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, foreign-keys, dto

Based on the question asked here: [Hibernate - Foreign keys instead of Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311776/hibernate-foreign-keys-instead-of-entities)

If I were to implement the following example:

```
@JoinColumn(name="message_key")
@ManyToOne(targetEntity=Message.class,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Message message;

@Column(name="message_key", updatable=false, insertable=false)
private Long message_fk;
```

Wouldn't this affect `Entity` to `DTO` conversion? In this case, during conversion, the object graph will include the mappings of the `Message` object as well?

Would the following code behave in the exact same manner without the traversal of the `Message` object?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table")
public class Example {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    // more properties

    @Column(name = "message_key")
    private Long messageKey;

    // more properties

    @Override
    public Long getMessageKey() {
        return messageKey();
    }

    @Override
    public void setMessageKey(Long messageKey) {
        this.messageKey = messageKey;
    }

    // More getters and setters
}
```

In this case, there is already a column in the DDL for `table` named `message_key`, so a foreign key relationship is not entirely necessary however I just need the generated `id` to populate that column.

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand your question, how are you converting the Entity to a DTO? Are you using an already existing mapper, or doing it manually?

Comment: Using an existing mapper

Comment: Normally, in those mappers you can define exceptions to the rule, meaning, you can say which properties you do not want to be copied, that should be more than enough

Comment: @MárioFernandes using Mapstruct, the Message object could be ignored but by ignoring it we are now unable to access certain properties of the Message object. In this case, all I needed was the Long property in the Messages object.

Comment: Why are you trying to access the Long property inside the Messages object, if you already have it as private Long message_fk?