# Adding both object and foreign key to a Spring Data JPA entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Below is an example of how I am defining my JPA entity. I am a bit confused on how to have both the object and the foreign key specified for ApplicationUser. I initially just had the ApplicationUser user property, but then realized I want to be able to query on the applicationUserId by defining a method in the ProductRepository such as findByApplicationUserId(long applicationUserId) and the repo keeps saying field does not exist. This is why I tried adding an applicationUserId property to the class and now there appears to be interference when running the application.

```
@Entity
public class Product{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private long applicationUserId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "application_user_id")
    private ApplicationUser user;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6312018/4207306

Comment: delete "long applicationUserId". Change the repository method to "findByUserId" (User because your field is named as user) and it's gonna be ok

Comment: @DaimonCool ahh... I think I am going crazy. Completely forgot the field is called user. Thank you!

Comment: @Blake Rivell You are welcome. It's ok) sometimes it happens. Maybe you just need some sleep :)