# The correct way to access referenced entity field

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm not familiar with Hibernate, and I saw this piece of code in a new project today:

```java
public abstract class ValidationCode {

    @Column(name = "userId", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private long userId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", referencedColumnName = "userId")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private MasterUser user;

    // ....
}
```

My question is that is it redundant to declare `userId` field like this? Can we not just use a `getter`?
Or maybe it values when in some cases like if we set the fetch type of user to be `Lazy`, we could access the `userId` field without fetching the user entity?

What would you suggest?

Comment: In what way do you think the declaration of `userId` is redundant?  Are you referring to the fact that there's a `@Column` annotation on the field `userId` rather than on the getter `getUserId()`?

Comment: Seems duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311776/hibernate-foreign-keys-instead-of-entities

Comment: @code_mechanic Thanks, I learnt a lot from the conversation from the post. Closing this as it's similar to the referenced one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are correct when you see this redundant. The `@ManyToOne` annotation specifies `JoinColumn(name = "userId", ...` which means the table where `ValidationCode` entity will be stored has a column `userId` that will be joined against the table where `MasterUser` is stored (and there, against a column named `userId` also).
On the other hand the `userId` attribute is also mapped to a `userId` column on the table where `ValidationCode` is stored.

Now, honestly I don't know if this works. And if it does work what actually happens with those attributes. Also both have `@Setter` which makes things worse.

Comment: Yes, two `@Setter` thing is aweful. For some reason, once while updating such entity, I have to set new values for both `userId` and `user`, if only update the `user` entity, `userId` in the entity will not be updated.